# If $\tan(\pi/9), x, \tan(5\pi/18)$ are in arithmetic progression, as are $\tan(\pi/9),y,\tan(7\pi/18)$, then ...

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

> If $\tan\frac{\pi}{9},x,\tan\frac{5\pi}{18}$ are in arithmetic progression and $\tan\frac{\pi}{9},y,\tan\frac{7\pi}{18}$ are, as well, then
>
> $(A)\;x=y\qquad(B)\;x=2y\qquad(C)\;2x=y\qquad(D)\;x+y=\frac{\pi}{2}$

**My Attempt:**

I used $2b=a+c$ ($\because$ It is an A.P.) for both cases and the subtracted both equations to get an equation in $x$ and $y$ on LHS and tan terms on RHS.

I then converted $\tan$ to $\sin$ and $\cos$ ($\tan A-\tan B=\sin(A-B)/\cos A\cos B$) and then converted the $\cos$ terms in denominator to $\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)$.

But I cannot find what to do further.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall convert everything to degrees, for convenience.

Note that $x = \frac 12(\tan 50 + \tan 20) = \frac 12(\tan 70(1-\tan 50 \tan 20) )= \frac 12(\tan 70 - \tan 50)$, since $\tan 70 \tan 20 = 1$.

Adding the previous two expressions, $4x = (\tan 70 + \tan 50 -\tan 50 + \tan 20)= \tan 70 + \tan 20$. We already know that $2y = \tan 70 + \tan 20$.

It is easy to see that $2x=y$ from this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw I figured out that for me, it's relatively easy to solve problems when angle is in degrees rather than radians.

Comment: @Cheapstrikev  That's great. I was never very comfortable with radians, and also when you have to write in radians, you have this very irritating \frac construct that I  get bored of, even with copy-pasting. So it's good that you are also familiar with degrees.